# PHP - obtaining sub-array in a single expression

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to get, in a single expression, a sub-array from an array, giving specific keys from the original array?

By example:

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' = 4, 'd' => 'clorch')
$b = doesthisfunctionexist($a, 'a', 'c')
//$b containing array('a' => 1, 'c' => 4)
```

I know I can code that function, but I'm asking if such a similar native function exists.

Comment: Do you mean `array_key_exists()`? For example: `true === array_key_exists('a', ['a' => 1]);`. It only works for one key at a time though. http://ie2.php.net/array_key_exists

Comment: array_key_exists is not what I expect. from the name one can infer the return value is boolean. from the doc one can confirm it. see what does $b contain in the third expression - that's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$a = array(
  "a" => 1,
  "b" => 2,
  "c" => 4,
  "d" => "clorch",
);
$b = array_intersect_key($a, array_flip(array('a', 'c')));
```

Comment: I was thinking about this alternative. Seems it's the only one I could figure using native functions (perhaps replacing array_flip with array_fill, but the idea was the same).

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of such a function but, you can do the following:

```
function array_pick($picks, $array)
    {
     $temp = array();
        foreach($array as $key => $value)
        {
            if(in_array($key, $picks))
            {
                $temp[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
     return $temp;
    }
```

try it like so:

```
 $a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' =>4, 'd' => 'clorch');
    $b = array('b','c');
    $z = array_pick($b,$a);
    var_dump($z);
```

output:

```
array(2) {
  ["b"]=>
  int(2)
  ["c"]=>
  int(4)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 4, 'd' => 'clorch');
$b = array_intersect_key($a, array_flip(array('a', 'c')));
```